# Trying to understand how classes and objects interact with one another - python

Tags: python, class

I am working through the examples from "Python Programming in Context" my Miller & Ranum.

I am working through the section on classes and we are building a solar system, and I am not clear on one certain part of the code.

```
class SolarSystem:

    def __init__(self, asun):
        self.thesun = asun
        self.planets = []

    def add_planet(self, aplanet):
        self.planets.append(aplanet)

    def show_planets(self):
        for aplanet in self.planets:
            print(aplanet)

    def num_planets(self):
        return len(self.planets)
```

I am not really sure how the `add_planet` and `show_planets` methods work exactly.  In the shell I created a some planets using the "Planet" class.  The planet class has more parameters than just name.  It also includes name, radius, mass, distance from the sun and number of moons.  When I pass a planet object to the SolarSystem class does the self.planets list contain all the arguments that were passed to the Planet object?  If so how does the `show_planet` method know to print out the just names of planets?  I think i may have missed something crucial here, one of the questions is to add a method for summing up the total mass in the solar system.  But I am not sure how to access the instance variable for mass from the Planets class so I can sum them in the SolarSystem class.

I hosted a repository on github since there is more than one file and I didn't want to paste it all here.  [solarsystem](https://github.com/spitfiredd/solarsystem)  That way you can see what I am talking about.

I hope this makes sense, just ask if you're unclear on anything.
Thanks

I added a total_mass method

```
def total_mass(self):
    total_mass = 0
    for aplanet in self.planets:
        total_mass = total_mass + get_mass(aplanet)
    return total_mass
```

It didn't work and I am not sure why.

I got it!
The last line should be:

```
total_mass = total_mass + aplanet.get_mass()
```

Comment: Where is your Planet class and attempt of using it?

Comment: @alexvassel: In the linked GitHub repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.planets` contains all of the `Planet` objects, which do contain `mass` and such in addition to `name`. The reason it prints the planet's name when you try to print the planet is that `print`, in order to print something, first needs to convert the object to a string. It can do this by passing the object to the `str` function. The `str` function converts it by calling `__str__` on the object. If you look at the definition of `Planet`, `__str__` returns the planet's name, so when the planet is printed, its name is printed.

Comment: ok i think i may see it now. To get the mass in the SolarSystem class I call the `get_mass` method from the planet class and from there I just create a for loop so sum them all up?

Comment: I added a total_mass method to the SolarSystem class.  I edited the main body above.  I get an error when I try to add up all the masses for each planet.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You probably need to invoke the object's method. Assuming your planets are all planet objects, and assuming `get_mass` is defined without any parameters (ie get_mass(self) in the planets module), you should be able to use `aplanet.get_mass()`.

Comment: @ erewok - thanks I actually just came to that conclusion myself..thank you though.  I think it's all starting to come together now.

Comment: But you should also try to read and interpret (and Google) the Tracebacks. They're the best way to decipher what's going wrong.